# Nodejs: How to export multiple objects?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm new to Nodejs. How to export multiple objects? For example

```
fs = require("fs")
Sequelize = require 'sequelize'

module.exports = (config)->
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database.name
    config.database.username
    config.database.password
    config.database.options
  )

  fs.readdirSync(config.root+'/server/models/').forEach (file)->
    module.exports['Page'] = sequelize.import(config.root + '/server/models/' + file) # --> export this model 
  sequelize # --> export this object
```

I want to use `Page` model something like:

```
Page = require('./models').Page
```

I want to use `Sequelize` object something like:

```
Sequelize = require('./models').Sequelize
```

Thank you for advice :D

**UPDATED**:
Solved following way:

```
fs = require("fs")
Sequelize = require 'sequelize'

module.exports = (config)->
  @Sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database.name
    config.database.username
    config.database.password
    config.database.options
  )

  fs.readdirSync(config.root+'/server/models/').forEach (file)->
    @Page = sequelize.import(config.root + '/server/models/' + file)
  @
```

but I have an another problem. How to assign models dynamically?

**UPDATED**
Solved second problem following way:

```
fs = require("fs")
Sequelize = require 'sequelize'

module.exports = (config)->
  @Sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database.name
    config.database.username
    config.database.password
    config.database.options
  )

  # @Page = sequelize.import(config.root + '/server/models/page')
  fs.readdirSync(config.root+'/server/models/').forEach (file)->
    str = file.replace('.coffee', '')
    model = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    @[model] = @Sequelize.import(config.root + '/server/models/' + file) if ~file.indexOf('.coffee')
  @
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just wrap them in an object literal. In pure JS (without CoffeeScript) that would be:

```
module.exports = {
    Page: {}, // or whatever you want to assign it to
    Serialize: {} // again, set it to what you like
};
```

In coffeescript you use indents, except when you want to make an empty object:

```
module.exports =
  Page: {},
  Serialize: {}
```

Comment: `=` should be `:` in the object literal :)

Comment: What do you mean by "How to assign models dynamically"?

Comment: Sorry for poor English. For example. I have 3 models in my `/server/models` folder. As you can see I'm loop through each models. Right now I'm just assign each models to `@Page` variable. How to make it dynamically.

Comment: How to assign each models to different variable like `@Page`?

Comment: You can use a string for the property name in pure JS. So instead of `Page: {}` you can use `"SomeName" : {}` and you can change "SomeName" to whatever you like. I don't know how this can be done in CoffeeScript.