# exporting multiple objects in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a MEAN stack project, and trying to pass a set of variables from one controller to another. My current approach is to export multiple objects for my `**artworks.js**` controller file:

```
module.exports = {
  Router: router,
  artists: distinctArtistsArray
}
```

The router object is a traditional Express router, but the **`distinctArtistsArray`** is a String array of all artists in my MongoDB database. I have an asynchronous function running in the background that every now and then populates **`distinctArtistsArray`**. This array is then passed into some other functions written elsewhere in order to do some NLP tasks behind the scenes.

I'd like another controller to have access to these variables as well, since I don't want to be placing undue load on my MongoDB by making duplicate async queries for artist information. Here's my other controller (**`complete.js`**):

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var ArtworkSearch = require('../controllers/artworks.js');
    console.log(ArtworkSearch.artists)
});
```

I've placed the **`require('../controllers/artworks/js')`** inside the callback function since I want to continuously reimport the values each time a request hits the `/complete` endpoint.

However, in my console, I receive an empty array (`[]`), which is what I initialize **`distinctArtistsArray`** to. FYI, I've followed the same exact method as the accepted answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122962/nodejs-how-to-export-multiple-objects) on a similar topic.

How do I get my list of artists to become available inside **`complete.js`** controller?

Comment: If `distinctArtistsArray` is initially empty, then how does it get a value.  You don't need to be able to reimport in order to see the latest value of that property.  Keep in mind that modules are cached so reimporting does NOT run your module again. It just returns the cached module from the first time.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that modules are cached in Node!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that required modules in NodeJS are cached. From Node's documentation:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

So you don't need to `require` the file again if you want the updated value, and you can move it outside the request callback.

You should instead export a function that returns the array, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  Router: router,
  artists: function () {
    return distinctArtistsArray
  }
}
```

and then

```
console.log(ArtworkSearch.artists())
```

You could also manually update the exported value in your code that periodically updates the `distinctArtistsArray` by running:

```
module.exports.artists = distinctArtistsArray
```

This needs to be done every time you update the `distinctArtistsArray`.