# Export class and function in the same file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class in JS file like:

```
class A {

  contructor(){}

  //logic
}
```

and in the same file I fave functions:

```
async function b(){}
```

and in the end I export class:

```
module.exports = A;
```

Can I export also function "b"?

Comment: `module.exports = {A, b};`?

Comment: Do you want to make them static methods of your class? And how do you expect the user of the file to import them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exporting multiple objects in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626936/exporting-multiple-objects-in-node-js) and [Nodejs: How to export multiple objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122962)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
class A {}

export async function b() {}

export default A
```

Elaborating:

You can have multiple named exports for a module but only a single default export. Most people would say it's good to have a default export for a file and then export any other modules as named exports.

For your issue you can see above that you could have the default export of A and then also use b as a named export. This could then be imported elsewhere as so:

`import A, { b } from '../foo';`

You likely would see this style with most OSS for example:

`import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';`

The import outside of the `{}` is the default export and the imports inside the `{}` are the named exports.

Comment: OP appears to be using commonjs modules, so no this won't work.

Comment: Hello @Josh, SO recommends that you explain your answer (along with the code) in order to consider as a qood quality answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AnjanaSilva I've expanded on my original answer.

Comment: @Josh : Great stuff. Appreciate your explanation. Keep it up. Cheers

Comment: module.exports = {Authorization, getTxHash}; is enough. I was tired. Thanks @JoshKelly and others.